# How to model an object owned by two different entities?

Tags: php, oop, architecture, software-design

Lets say if two families, Smiths and Johns have two lawn movers of same make and manufacture, how can I model this scenario in programming?

I mean as both the lawn movers will have separate serial numbers I can map them to two different objects and this is closed to real world situation.

Or should I just create only one object and share it among two families which is completely different from real world scenario.

Which is the best practice which can reduce problems in future and provide feasibility?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You can do this by creating one class, that represents the lawn mover with a field for owner.  When you create an instance of this class, you can then specify the owner and thereby link it correctly. When initialised there will be two instances of this class that are linked to their respective owners.

Comment: Lawnmover will be an instance of a "Physical item", or whatever you want to call it (Machine?). It's blueprint will have the properties; name, manufacturer and serial_number. The families would be made from the class blueprint "Family" and then named differently (name = "Smiths", name = "Johns"). The Family blueprint does not inherit the Machine instance Lawnmower, that doesn't make sense. You can give the Family an "inventory" Array property, which can then contain an instance of a Machine instance of Lawnmower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your lawn mover as separate object, and family object should own a lawn mover.
This is "has-a" relationship and you can use composition. So family object can have property lawn mover where their lawn mover will be stored. And you can access family lawn mover through family object like this:

```
$family = new Family();
$family->lawnMover->start();
```

Family should not extend lawn mover since that is "is-a" relationship and lawn mover is not a family! It belongs to family, so family "has-a" lawn mover.

I think you should always go with real world examples.
Read about: [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)

In short DDD is when you try to mimic real world using OOP.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic, and might not be the perfect example according to different programmers, but here goes;

```
class Family {
    public $name;
    public $inventory = array();

    public function __construct($name = '') {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function add_inventory_item($object) {
        if (is_object($object)) {
            $this->inventory[] = $object;

            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

class Machine {
    public $name;
    public $manufacturer;
    public $serial_number;

    public function __construct($name = '', $manufacturer = '', $serial_number = '') {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;
        $this->serial_number = $serial_number;
    }
}

$fam_smiths = new Family('Smiths');
$fam_johns = new Family('Johns');

$lawnmower_a = new Machine('Lawnmower A', 'Some company A', '1234');
$lawnmower_b = new Machine('Lawnmower B', 'Some company B', '5678');

if ($fam_smiths->add_inventory_item($lawnmower_a)) {
    echo 'Lawnmower A added to family Smiths\' their inventory.<br /><br />';
}
else {
    echo 'Lawnmower A doesn\t have the correct strucure.<br /><br />';
}

if ($fam_johns->add_inventory_item($lawnmower_b)) {
    echo 'Lawnmower B added to family Johns\' their inventory.<br /><br />';
}
else {
    echo 'Lawnmower B doesn\t have the correct strucure.<br /><br />';
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($fam_smiths);
print_r($fam_johns);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Lawnmower A added to family Smiths' their inventory.

Lawnmower B added to family Johns' their inventory.

Family Object
(
    [name] => Smiths
    [inventory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Machine Object
                (
                    [name] => Lawnmower A
                    [manufacturer] => Some company A
                    [serial_number] => 1234
                )

        )

)
Family Object
(
    [name] => Johns
    [inventory] => Array
        (
            [0] => Machine Object
                (
                    [name] => Lawnmower B
                    [manufacturer] => Some company B
                    [serial_number] => 5678
                )

        )

)
```

You could also make a super class construction, where Lawnmower would be a Class too, inheriting all basics of a Machine.